# When stopping IMFSourceReader how can I ensure that OnReadSample will not be called again?

Tags: thread-safety, ms-media-foundation

I am using the Media Framework SDK to capture video from a camera.
My code is based on the [MFCaptureD3D](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/mediafoundation/MFCaptureD3D) example.
My code and this example use the IMFSourceReader to read frames from the camera asynchronously. For this the application provides an implementation of  IMFSourceReaderCallback whose OnReadSample is called from an MFSDK thread with every frame that becomes available.

The example works, except that I could not find a reliable way of stopping the camera capture. In particular, even after calling Stop and Shutdown on the source reader, occasionally the OnReadSample callback may be invoked. If, after calling Stop and Shutdown the application disposes of resources that are used in OnReadSample, then OnReadSample will crash.

I am looking for a call that would join any pending threads that might possibly still call OnReadSample such that when that function returns OnReadSample is guaranteed not to be called again.

Comment: I solved this problem with a flag, a mutex and a condition variable but it did not make Stop() safe. Unless I do a sleep after calling sourcereader->Shutdown and before calling start I get a crash in the MFSDK.

Comment: Have you tried calling IMFSourceReader::Flush as well (or you meant Flush when you said Stop)? 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/mfreadwrite/nf-mfreadwrite-imfsourcereader-flush
You'll have to wait for OnFlush to dispose of the resources.

Answer (score 1):

Late `OnReadSample` callbacks are possible due to multi-threaded nature of application and such invocations being initiated from worker threads. Unlike other samples that for code brevity cut corners in callback object implementation, `MFCaptureD3D` is implementing callback on a class `CPreview` with normal reference counting. There might be a late `CPreview::OnReadSample` call and then it is followed by `IMFSourceReaderCallback::Release` call which is expected to delete `CPreview` instance (unless you reference it for other needs).

Having said that,

- be sure that your reference counting and interface management is okay
- stop capture as you already do
- be ready to have rare late callbacks
- in your class that takes the callbacks you can add a flag indicating state of termination and check it to immediately return and do nothing, e.g. [here in line 189](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/master/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/mediafoundation/MFCaptureD3D/preview.cpp#L189); when you are stopping the capture, set also this flag in your callback class to ignore late calls
- in case of late callback your callback class still has a COM interface reference from the API; the helper flag would protect you from doing anything harmful
- you can check for release of COM interface and deletion of the callback object in case you want to be sure no further callback are coming, but I would say that with the suggested flag you don't nee to do it as the resources will be freed accurately even though possibly with a slight delay caused by multi-threading

Answer (score 1):

Though the answers and comments posted here were useful, they were not the cause of the problem in my case.

The actual problem was that a sample was arriving after I had destroyed the callback object. I thought I had solved this using a "flag, a mutex and a condition variable" as described in my comment, but that implementation was incorrect. 
The solution that solved the problem was the following:

1. Define two 64 bit counters receivedSamples and requestedSamples. In addition, a "stopped" flag, a mutex and a condition variable.
2. Upon Start, lock the mutex and set the counters to 0 and the stopped flag to false. Then call sourceReader->ReadSample to initiate receipt of the first sample.
3. In Stop, lock the mutex, set the stopped flog to true and use the condition variable to wait until receivedSamples == requestedSamples.
4. In OnReadSample, lock the mutex, increment the receivedSamples counter, unlock the mutex and notify the condition variable.
5. Just before the call to sourceReader->ReadSample lock the mutex (if not already owned) increment the requestedSamples counter.

I will add a code snipped that demonstrates this shortly